# Arrays.asList issue when computing square root of integer array elements

Tags: java, arrays, list, square-root

I'm trying to write a code which gets a array of ints and checks if the square root of the number is in the array, if yes it will print yes else it will print no.
I can't figure out why my code returns no all the time.

For example if my input is : 1 4 0 2 16 3

My output will be : yes yes yes no yes no

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Assignment02Q04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] intlist = new int[args.length]; 
        for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
            intlist[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }

        for (int number : intlist) {
            int sqrt = (int)(Math.sqrt(number)); 
            System.out.println(sqrt); 
            if (Arrays.asList(intlist).contains(sqrt)) {
                System.out.println("yes");
            } else {
                System.out.println("no"); 
            }
        }
   }            
}
```

Comment: Can't say just from the code. Maybe... try using Integer instead of int. List works better with objects rather than primitives.

Comment: @CoolGuy this doesn't answer the question, since he wants to check the entire original array for that number.

Comment: Integer[] intlist instead of int[] intlist

Comment: @MuhammadHijazi , Oops! You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a collection from the start, instead of continuously converting, using Arrays.asList().
Also, check that the number has a natural square root by using floor on the square root and comparing it's power of 2 to the original number. Here is the code which returns the expected result yes yes yes no yes no:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> intlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        intlist.add(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
    }

    for (int number : intlist) {
        int sqrt = (int) (Math.floor(Math.sqrt(number)));
        if (sqrt * sqrt == number && intlist.contains(sqrt)) {
            System.out.print("yes ");
        } else { 
            System.out.print("no ");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`Arrays.asList(intlist)` returns a list of arrays `int[]`. The `int[]` array itself is here treated as *single object* that is passed to the method:

```
// the return is a list of arrays; arrays are objects in Java
List<int[]> asList = Arrays.asList(intlist);
```

You can resolve this by using an array of `Integer` objects instead.

```
Integer[] intlist = new Integer[args.length]; 
for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
    intlist[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes because the square root values of {1, 4, 0, 2, 16, 3} are {1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1} and they all exist in the list.

Comment: the square root of 2 is 1.41, but the decimals are lost at conversion from double to int. Therefor, the answer is false.

Comment: @Adrian The OP should obviously avoid the conversion but that's not the main cause of the problem he or she is facing.

Comment: yeah , watch too much code and no logic XD
anyway think code is "solved" =)